# glibc malloc guard byte wrapper

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc, glibc

I'm trying to add a guard char at the very end of each allocated chunk so that `free()` can `abort()` if it does not find it. Why are these function preloads not working? I realize this is not a portable method but I was curious why it is not working.

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -std=gnu99 -O2 -o wrapper.so wrapper.c

LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/wrapper.so programname
```

I have one function for each: `valloc`, `realloc`, `pvalloc`, `posix_memalign`, `aligned_alloc`, `memalign`, `malloc` and `calloc`.

```
#define PREV_INUSE 0x1
#define IS_MMAPPED 0x2
#define NON_MAIN_ARENA 0x4
#define SIZE_BITS (PREV_INUSE|IS_MMAPPED|NON_MAIN_ARENA)


extern void *__libc_malloc(size_t size);
void *malloc(size_t size){
    size = size + 1; // add char for guard byte '@'

    void *p = __libc_malloc(size);

    if(p != NULL){
        size_t *q = p;
        q--;
        size_t s = *q & ~(SIZE_BITS); // get allocated bytes subtracting info bits
        char *z = p;
        memset(z, 0, s); // zero memory
        z[s - 1] = '@'; // place guard char
    }

    return p;
}

extern void *__libc_free(void *ptr);
void free(void *ptr){
    if(ptr != NULL){
        size_t *p = ptr;
        p--;
        size_t s = *p & ~(SIZE_BITS);
        char *z = ptr;
        if(z[s - 1] != '@') // if guard char not found, abort()
        {
            abort();
        }
        memset(z, 0, s); // zero memory
    }

    __libc_free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: You should really avoid one letter variables names as much as possible, they are unreadable and ungrepable.

Comment: if you are using glibc, you are probably work on something that is already done. See `man 3 mcheck`.

Comment: `LD_DEBUG=symbols LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/wrapper.so programname 2>&1 | grep malloc`. What if take a look at finding malloc?

Comment: @Grady chromium = aborted, gedit = segfault, regexxer = segfault, gimp = segfault

Comment: @skwllsp I don't follow. But outputs shows many lines: symbol=malloc, symbol=__malloc_initialize_hook, symbol=__malloc_hook, symbol=pcre_malloc, etc.

Comment: OK, take a look at the whole file: `LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT=symbols.txt LD_DEBUG=symbols LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/wrapper.so programname`. Get symbols.txt and find a library that was chosen to bind `malloc`. If it is not your library, then it is useful to see what symbols it exports with `nm -D /path/to/wrapper.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `size_t` located just before the allocated area as the length available. However, it *includes* the `size_t` itself. Therefore, here:

```
    if (p != NULL) {
        size_t *q = p;
        q--;
        size_t s = *q & ~(SIZE_BITS); // get allocated bytes subtracting info bits
        char *z = p;
        memset(z, 0, s); // zero memory
        z[s - 1] = '@'; // place guard char
    }
```

you end up overwriting the length of the *next* region, partially, by your guard char. The solution is to substract the length of the length field in bytes, i.e. use `const s = (((size_t *)p)[-1] & (~(size_t)SIZE_BITS)) - sizeof (size_t);` instead.

(I verified this works on Embedded GNU C Library 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 on x86-64, for both 64 and 32-bit code (with different `size_t` sizes).)

I recommend you add at least minimal abstraction, so that porting your code to a different C library or a newer version of GNU C library in the future is not futile. (Version checking would be good, but I was too lazy to find out which versions of GNU C library actually use this layout.)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#ifdef __GLIBC__

/* GLIBC stuffs the length just prior to the returned pointer,
 * with flags in the least significant three bits. It includes
 * the length field itself. */
#define   USER_LEN(ptr) ( ( ((size_t *)(ptr))[-1] & (~((size_t)7)) ) - sizeof (size_t))

#else
#error This C library is not supported (yet).
#endif

extern void  abort(void);
extern void *__libc_malloc(size_t);
extern void *__libc_realloc(void *, size_t);
extern void  __libc_free(void *);


#define CANARY_LEN 1

static void canary_set(void *const ptr, const size_t len)
{
    ((unsigned char *)ptr)[len - CANARY_LEN] = '@';
}

static int canary_ok(const void *const ptr, const size_t len)
{
    return ((const unsigned char *)ptr)[len - CANARY_LEN] == '@';
}


void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr;
    ptr = __libc_malloc(size + CANARY_LEN);
    if (ptr) {
        const size_t len = USER_LEN(ptr);
        memset(ptr, 0, len);
        canary_set(ptr, len);
    }
    return ptr;
}

void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
    void *newptr;

    if (!ptr)
        return malloc(size);

    if (!canary_ok(ptr, USER_LEN(ptr)))
        abort();

    newptr = __libc_realloc(ptr, size + CANARY_LEN);
    if (!newptr)
        return newptr;

    canary_set(newptr, USER_LEN(ptr));

    return newptr;
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
    if (ptr) {
        const size_t len = USER_LEN(ptr);

        if (!canary_ok(ptr, len))
            abort();

        memset(ptr, 0, len);

        __libc_free(ptr);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apparently, it is (2 * sizeof(size_t)). [malloc.c](http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#1119). Also, I cannot get it to work with chromium. Possible buffer overflow at their end?

Comment: @liyong: The comment *"Each malloced chunk has a hidden word of overhead holding size and status information"* near line 105 would indicate just one-word overhead; I haven't bothered to dive deep into the code itself, so I might be wrong and you right -- I don't think so, though. As to Chromium: Chromium uses it's own malloc implementation, I believe; you'd need a different approach (especially run-time symbol address resolution via `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"malloc")`-obtained function pointers) to work with *any* `malloc()` implementation; the one here is absolutely GLIBC-only.